# C - Read file byte by byte using fread

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to read a file byte by byte (this is important because I have to measure performance). I can't seem to get the fread to work properly. Right now it just gives me the last byte of the file.

This is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    FILE *fileptr;
    char *buffer;
    long filelen;
    int i;

    fileptr = fopen(argv[1], "rb");         
    fseek(fileptr, 0, SEEK_END);          
    filelen = ftell(fileptr);            
    rewind(fileptr);                      
    buffer = (char *)malloc((filelen+1)*sizeof(char)); 

    for(i = 0; i < filelen; i++) {
       fread(*&buffer, 1, 1, fileptr); 
    }

    printf("File len: %ld\n", filelen);
    printf("%s\n",*&buffer);

    fclose(fileptr); // Close the file

    return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The os is going to buffer stuff, so measuring performance like this is not very meaningfull

Comment: Also, `*&buffer` is actually the same as `buffer` or `&buffer[0]`. This is because `&` takes the address of the variable `buffer`, creating a pointer of type `char**`, then `*` dereferences that pointer, turning it back into the same `char*` that we started from, aka `buffer`.

Comment: @OldProgrammer What would be a good way? I just need to measure how long it takes to read the file.

Comment: `*&buffer` doesn't seem not wrong to me :-) And don't do `(char *) malloc ((filelen+1) * sizeof(char))` in C, it's better _not_ to cast, and `sizeof(char)` is _always_ one.

Comment: I have no idea why you would want this at all (silly assignment maybe?), but  here it is: I personally think the system buffering should be counted into the performance measurements. A few million function calls should, on the other hand, not be measured, thus I would replace the loop entirely with `fread(buffer, filelen, 1, fileptr);` Also, any data you get will probably be garbage for files below a few tens, maybe hundreds of MiB, I would think.

Comment: If you're reading one byte at a time, just use `getc` instead of `fread`. `fread` is defined to work as if by repeated calls to `getc` or `fgetc` anyway.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I did not say `*&buffer` was wrong, I just said it was about as meaningful as `*&*&*&*&*&*&*&buffer` of `buffer+1-1`. :)

Comment: @RudolfW, that comment was directed more toward the OP than you. I have no issues with your comments, other than the use of `of` when you probably meant `or` :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to advance the pointer:

```
for(i = 0; i < filelen; i++) {
       fread(buffer+i, 1, 1, fileptr); 
}
```

Currently, at every iteration the loop overwrites the previous character. No surprise then that only the last character appears.

By the way, you should add a '\0' character after the loop, which will mark the end of the string, so that `printf()` will stop printing after it.